# Key error in dict when applying lambda function over Pyspark

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda, pyspark, key

I have a dataframe `df` with some columns. I am trying to do something and I get a strange error instead of a result I am expecting.

My idea is to generate a numeric value for each distinct value of the dataframe column, and add the pair `"real_value" : "numeric_value"` to a dictionary.

The global dictionary where save the results is:

```
dict_res = {}
```

I have the next function that passing a value and the attribute name, gets the dictionary according to the atr from the global dictionary "dict_res" and if the value exists as a key into the dictionary, returns its numeric value, and if not, generates a new numeric value defined as `float(len(dict_res[atr]) + 1)`.

```
def indexMethod(value, atr):
    global dict_res
    res = float(len(dict_res[atr]) + 1)
    if value in dict_res[atr]:
        res = dict_res[atr][value]
    else:
        dict_res[atr][value] = res
    return res
```

The next code fragment iterates over the attributes I want to generate a numeric value from, and if a dictionary equivalent to the attribute is not created into the global dictionary "dict_res" it is created, and then applies with a lambda function the method specified above.

```
for column in columns_to_index:
    udf_func = UserDefinedFunction(lambda value: indexMethod(value, column), DoubleType())
    if(not column in dict_res):
        dict_res[column] = {}
    col2 = udf_func(df[column])
    df = df.withColumn('newCol', col2)
    ....
```

So what I expect is to generate the dictionary with the equivalences, as well as a new column with those same equivalences as in the dictionary.

After the process, I print the dict as follows:

```
print(dict_res)
```

And the result I get is the next one:

```
{'ATR1': {}, 'ATR2': {}, ...}
```

So the dictionaries are empty. But the most significant error is that when I try to show the dataframe 'df' I get the next error:

```
KeyError: 'ATR1'
```

How is that possible if I have a dictionary with that key?

Hope you can help me...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can update an exterior python object (global or not) through a `UDF` that only operates actions on rows.

Another way to solve the problem is to use `distinct()`:

```py
dict_res = dict()
for column in columns_to_index:
    dict_res[column] = df.select(column).distinct().toPandas().to_dict()
```

Comment: It is useful when I have a dataframe and it will not be escaled more. But if later on I have new data that I want to process too, and I want to combine the results with the ones already gotten in the dictionary 'dict_res'? Thanks for the response, anyway!

Comment: You can use `subtract`, then `distinct` and append the new data to the existing dictionaries.